# Neo4j problems storing nodes with large properties

Tags: java, json, rest, neo4j

I try to create some nodes in Neo4j with Java via CYPHER, more specifically with JSON and `http://hostname:7474/db/data/transaction/commit`.

My test should create some nodes with the following CYPHER statements:

```
MERGE (a:LABEL1 { name: 'nameNNN', version: 1001 })
SET a.PROP1='<data>'
RETURN id(a)
```

As long as  is small, e.g. one or more properties with < 1kB in the sum, everything works. If a try to write nodes with a larger property (10MB binary data base64 encoded for
example), the test creates 9 or 10 nodes:

```
{errors=[], results=[{"data":[{"row":[10009]}],"columns":["id(a)"]}]}
{errors=[], results=[{"data":[{"row":[10010]}],"columns":["id(a)"]}]}
...
{errors=[], results=[{"data":[{"row":[10011]}],"columns":["id(a)"]}]}
```

and then starts to return:

```
{errors=[], results=[]}
```

If I restart the test, I get immediately the empty result. If I restart the Neo4j Server,
I can either update these 9 or 10 nodes or create 9 or 10 nodes with different names and
then again I get only empty results.

As I understand it, every statement is a single transaction (I execute one merge per server request).

Is this a bug, or a limit of the community edition (2.1.6) or do I something wrong?

Comment: Make sure to use parameters for your statements not plain data in the query.

Comment: Also make sure you have an index/constraint at least on :Label1(name)

Comment: If you have literal data in there, perhaps something breaks the parsing of the string?

Comment: I still don't understand why it works n times and then fails without error. But the first hint (use parameters) seems to help. I could do only a small test yet, but instead of failing after the 12th query I could create >= 300 such nodes and it is also considerable faster. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It's one of the very few antipatterns for Neo4j to store large chunks of blob data in a property. The recommended approach is to move those to a datastore suitable for large blobs (e.g. Amazon S3 and others) and keep URI references to them within Neo4j.

So the node representing the blob content then has an `uri` property pointing to the external blob store.

Comment: We evaluate a few databases for a future project and there is a test frame given which contains also some tests with large attributes. Such large attributes are rather seldom, but should work if they occur. Even if its not the best solution, I assumed that it will work. But it does not work. I have to restart the server after 9 such write operations. My question is: Is this a bug, or do I something wrong? Does this depend on the size of the single attribute or may I run into the same problem only later if I write some more, but smaller, nodes.

Comment: AFAIK jersey (which is used under the hoods) does have some limitation in request size. You might want to try to use lengthy properties when running Neo4j in embedded mode (see manual).

Comment: I don't think jersey limitations are a problem, because it works for some time (every merge is a single request). I tried with different sizes and the number of nodes and runtime go up with smaller sizes:
Size: 11184812 ->  12, 187s
Size:  5592408 ->  26, 225s
Size:  2796204 ->  56, 240s
Size:  1572864 ->  99, 243s
Size:  1561944 -> 101, 254s
Size:  1560576 -> 101, 253s
Size:  1560000 -> 102, 267s
Size:  1559736 -> 108, 321s
Size:  1559600 -> 117, 403s
Size:  1559536 -> 125, 474s
Size:  1559468 -> 150, 708s

There seems to be some magical border in this size range around 1.5M

Answer (score 0):

If I use parameters instead of data in the query, the problem does not occur. Thanks for that hint!